# Jquery UI - Sortable & Draggable revert speed

Tags: jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

i have a problem with the revert speed.

Here is a working example
http://www.jsfiddle.net/V9Euk/94/   <-- updated

Change something in the sortable list ... the speed is fast (revert 100).
But when you drop the "four" into the sortable list, the speed is slow.

But why? oO

kind reagards
Peter

Comment: your closing tag for the `<ul>` is incorrect... you have `</li>` and it should be `</ul>`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the code... except that it was invalid. You had a incorrectly closed tag, and other oddities inside the code that once cleaned up resolved the problem. I think. Unless it isn't what you was asking about.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <ul id="k1" style="width:350px; height:350px; margin:20px;">
            <li>One</li>
            <li>Two</li>
            <li>Three</li>
        </ul>
        <hr />
        <ul style="width:350px; height:350px;">
            <li class="gt">Four</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-size: 12px;
}

li{
    border:1px solid #444444;
    background-color:#AAAAAA;
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("#k1").sortable({   revert: '100'  });
$('.gt').draggable({ connectToSortable: '#k1', revert: 'invalid', revertDuration: 100 });
```

**Edit**: Sorry, I misread the question. The code was slightly confusing, and I missed the problem. The solution is a little bit of a kludge, but I think it will work.

```
var original = $('#k1');

original.sortable({ revert: 100  });
$('.gt').draggable({
    connectToSortable: original,
    revert: 'valid',
    revertDuration: 100,
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        original.sortable("option", "revert", 100);
    }
});
```

Basically it re-set the revert option on the `k1` div after `.gt` is dropped.

Comment: Sort the list = revertspeed is 100 ..... 
Drop the four into the list and sort = revertspeed is slow

Comment: Thanx! It works, only the dropspeed is slow. http://www.jsfiddle.net/V9Euk/100/ ...

Answer (score 1):

Now you can achieve this with :

```
$("#selector").sortable({revert: 500});
```